# Powershell: Write generated table to html file

Tags: html, powershell

i have two files in total,

1. PowerShell script
2. HTML file

With the help of the script I create a html table.
I would like to set the table content to a fixed position in the html file .

```
<table class="Class_OPC_Item">
    <col style="width: 300px;">
    <col style="width: 50px;">
    <col style="width: 50px;">
    <col style="width: 50px;">
    <col style="width: *;">
    
    <!-- $$$OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES START$$$ -->
        <!-- $$$OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES END$$$ -->

    <a href="#footnote_10">Footnotes</a>
</table>
```

This is my current code where im generating and Converting my html:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
$Choosefile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog
$Choosefile.Filter ="UAR-Files (*.uar)|*.uar"
$Choosefile.ShowDialog()

if($Choosefile.FileName -ne "")
{
    #Path to .uar-File
    [xml]$uar = Get-Content -Path $ChooseFile.FileName

    #Says that we are using namespaces
    $ns = New-Object System.Xml.XmlNamespaceManager($uar.NameTable)

    #namespaces of XML
    $ns=@{asdf="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2011/03/UANodeSet.xsd";
        ua="http://br-automation.com/OpcUa/configuration/NodeSet.xsd";
        xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance";
        uax="http://opcfoundation.org/UA/2008/02/Types.xsd";
        xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
        pv="http://br-automation.com/OpcUa/PLC/PV.xsd"}

    #Lookuptable for DataTypes
    $LookUpTable=@{
    "i=1"="Boolean"
    "i=2"="Sbyte"
    "i=3"="Byte"
    "i=4"="Int16"
    "i=5"="UInt16"
    "i=6"="Int32"
    "i=7"="UInt32"
    "i=8"="Int64"
    "i=9"="UInt64"
    "i=10"="Float"
    "i=11"="Double"
    "i=12"="String"
    "i=13"="DateTime"
    "i=15"="ByteString"
    "i=21"="LocalizedText"
    "i=35"="Organizes"
    "i=37"="HasModellingRule"
    "i=38"="HasEncoding"
    "i=39"="HasDescription"
    "i=40"="HasTypeDefinition"
    "i=45"="HasSubtype"
    "i=46"="HasProperty"
    "i=47"="HasComponent"
    "i=69"="DataTypeDescriptionType"
    "i=72"="DataTypeDictionaryType"
    "i=76"="DataTypeEncodingType"
    "i=294"="Argument"
    "i=296"="UtcTime"
    "i=7594"="EnumValueType"
    }

    #XPATH with namespaces. Only Valid DataTypes and NodeId´s
    $result=Select-xml -xml $uar -xpath "//asdf:UAVariable[contains(@NodeId,'ns=1;s=::')][starts-with(@DataType,'i=')]" -namespace $ns  | select -ExpandProperty node

    #just a loop to replace "ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:"
    $result | foreach {$_.NodeId = $_.NodeId -replace 'ns=1;s=::AsGlobalPV:'}

    #another loop if its not GlobalPV
    $result | foreach {$_.NodeId = $_.NodeId -replace 'ns=1;s=::'}

    #2nd Array for writing my Valid nodes for html output (FINAL RESULT)
    $result2=@()   

    #loop to check if arrays are Valid
    $result | foreach{
        $AttExists = $_.Arraydimensions
        $NodeExists = $_.References.Reference.ReferenceType
        if ($AttExists)
        {
            if ($NodeExists -eq 'HasComponent')
            {            
                #Nothing we dont want Arraydeclarations
            }
            else
            {
                $result2 += $_   
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $result2 += $_ 
        }
    }

    #loop to split up "Description" and adding new values to array
    $result2 | foreach{
    $ChildExists=$_.Description
        if($ChildExists){
            if($ChildExists -match ';')
                {
                    $splitarray=$ChildExists.Split(";")
                    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scale" -value $splitarray[0]
                    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Unit" -value $splitarray[1]
                    $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Comment" -value $splitarray[2]
                }
            else
            {
                $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scale" -value ""
                $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Unit" -value ""
                $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Comment" -value $ChildExists
            }
        }
        else
        {
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Scale" -value ""
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Unit" -value ""
            $_ | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Comment" -value ""
        }
    }

    #loop for DataTypes translation
    $result2 | foreach{
        if($LookUpTable.ContainsKey($_.DataType))
        {
            $_.DataType=$LookUpTable[$_.DataType]
        }
    }

    $SaveFile = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.SaveFileDialog
    $SaveFile.Filter = "Html-Files (*.html)|*.html"
    $SaveFile.showdialog() | Out-Null

    $result2 | ConvertTo-Html `
    -Property NodeId, DataType, Scale, Unit, Comment `
    > $SaveFile.FileName
```

This html should be posted into another html between those 2 placeholder at the top.
Can anyone here help me or has done something similar and can give me a hint?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't show us anything at all.. no script, no html.. If you want help, you need to edit your question and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your placeholder boundaries on separate lines you can write a simple parser to concatenate the files:

```bsh
# Generate our html table
$HTMLTable = Get-HtmlTable # replace with your code

$allLines = switch -File .\path\to\template.html -WildCard {
    '*<!-- $$$OPC-ITEM-ENTRIES START$$$ -->*' {
        # append the HTML table
        $_
        $HTMLTable
    }
    default {
        # output the line as-is from the html template file by default
        $_
    }
}

# Output the whole thing to a new html file
$allLines |Set-Content .\output.html
```

Comment: Thank you but how can i do this Get-HtmlTable from my convert? Its not a Cmdlet or can say Get-Content from my generated file? And dont want a new html i just want to edit and save the existing. Is that possible?

Comment: yes its a simple html table and this hole content should be posted into the other one

Comment: Well, if the existing script outputs the HTML table to a file on disk, you'd simply read the contents of that file: `$HTMLTable = Get-Content .\path\to\table.html`

Comment: Its working thank you another question is it possible to delete the content between these 2 placeholders? Or should is make a new post?